# Add a field conditional on the other with a function

Tags: r

I apologize if the title may not be clear.

With

```
df <- data.frame(profit = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1),
                 offerA = round(rnorm(6), 2), 
                 offerB = round(runif(6), 2), 
                 offerC = sample(1:6))

df
  profit offerA offerB offerC
1      1  -0.51   0.91      6
2      1  -0.03   0.75      4
3      0  -1.02   0.28      5
4      0   0.63   0.61      1
5      0   2.32   0.37      2
6     -1  -0.15   0.43      3
```

I need to add a field named `bid` depending on the value of `profit` under the following conditions:

```
with(df,
  if (profit > 0) {
    apply(cbind(offerA, offerB, offerC), 1, max)
  }
  else if (profit = 0) {
    apply(cbind(offerA, offerB, offerC), 1, mean)
  }
  else if (profit < 0) {
    apply(cbind(offerA, offerB, offerC), 1, min)
  }
)
```

In this example the new `df` will be:

```
df
  profit offerA offerB offerC   bid
1      1  -0.51   0.91      6     6
2      1  -0.03   0.75      4     4
3      0  -1.02   0.28      5  1.42
4      0   0.63   0.61      1  0.75
5      0   2.32   0.37      2  1.56
6     -1  -0.15   0.43      3 -0.15
```

Because the value of `bid` is computed by rows, I want to write a function `addBid()` so that I can use something like `apply(df, 1, addBid)` but I can't think of a good way adding my conditions above into the function. I hope I'm clear with my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could be useful

```
bid <- function(x, ref, add=FALSE){
  ref <- match(ref,names(df))
  result <- ifelse(df[,ref]>0, apply(df[,-ref],1,max), 
         ifelse(df[,ref]==0, rowMeans(df[,-ref]),  apply(df[,-ref],1,min)) )
  if(add){
    result <- cbind(x, bid=result)
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Where `x` is your data.frame, `ref` is the reference variable (`profit`) and `add` is a logical indicating if you want `bid` as a vector (if `add=FALSE`) or your original data.frame with `bid` as a new column (if `add=TRUE`).

```
set.seed(001)
df <- data.frame(profit = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1),
                 offerA = round(rnorm(6), 2), 
                 offerB = round(runif(6), 2), 
                 offerC = sample(1:6))

> bid(df, ref='profit')  # returns a vector
[1]  3.000000  4.000000  1.643333  1.033333  1.016667 -0.820000
> bid(df, ref='profit', add=TRUE) # returns a data.frame = df + bid
  profit offerA offerB offerC       bid
1      1  -0.63   0.69      3  3.000000
2      1   0.18   0.38      4  4.000000
3      0  -0.84   0.77      5  1.643333
4      0   1.60   0.50      1  1.033333
5      0   0.33   0.72      2  1.016667
6     -1  -0.82   0.99      6 -0.820000
```

Comment: Nice thinking. Again, I would find `transform()` useful in these cases: `transform(df, bid = ifelse(profit > 0, apply(df[-1], 1, max), ifelse(profit == 0, rowMeans(df[-1]), apply(df[-1], 1, min))))`

Comment: @mrdwab that's very nice, you can post it as an answer so that can be accept it or upvoted. `transform()` was a candidate but I left it out :(

Comment: Thank you guys. All your answers are great. Since Jilber has slightly lower score, I'd accept his answer but hope I could accept multiple ones. +1 on everybody :)

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way of doing this is probably to use `transform()` or `within()` instead of writing a separate function. Using @Jilber's sample data (and the same transformation logic), here's an example using `transform()`:

```
transform(df, bid = ifelse(profit > 0, apply(df[-1], 1, max), 
                           ifelse(profit == 0, rowMeans(df[-1]), 
                                  apply(df[-1], 1, min))))
#   profit offerA offerB offerC       bid
# 1      1  -0.63   0.69      3  3.000000
# 2      1   0.18   0.38      4  4.000000
# 3      0  -0.84   0.77      5  1.643333
# 4      0   1.60   0.50      1  1.033333
# 5      0   0.33   0.72      2  1.016667
# 6     -1  -0.82   0.99      6 -0.820000
```

Comment: @Jilber, thanks... Didn't want to tread on your toes since we were both going down the `ifelse()` line of thought ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is something more elegant, but this works I think:

```
foo <- function(x){
    if (x[1] > 0){
        return(max(x[-1]))
    }
    if (x[1] == 0){
        return(mean(x[-1]))
    }
    if (x[1] < 0){
        return(min(x[-1]))
    }
}

df$bid <- apply(df,1,foo)
df
  profit offerA offerB offerC       bid
1      1  -0.17   0.14      2  2.000000
2      1   1.75   0.46      5  5.000000
3      0   0.38   0.90      1  0.760000
4      0   0.34   0.35      4  1.563333
5      0   0.22   0.63      3  1.283333
6     -1  -1.09   0.34      6 -1.090000
```